# Creating an if/then in Excel for time

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm looking for a way to subtract 45 minutes if the value of the time in the cell is greater than 5 hours. 
But the destination cell is calculating the time from two other cells already using this formula:

```
=TEXT(G3-F3+(G3<F3), "h:mm")
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your formula looks incomplete, can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1420965/edit) to provide it in its entirety?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad The formula was getting cut off because of formatting. I've moved it to a code block, and the edit is pending review. Here it is in the meantime: `=TEXT(G3-F3+(G3<F3), "h:mm")`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(TIMEVALUE(TEXT(G3-F3+(G3<F3), "h:mm"))>TIME(5,0,0),TIMEVALUE(TEXT(G3-F3+(G3<F3), "h:mm"))-TIME(0,15,0),TIMEVALUE(TEXT(G3-F3+(G3<F3), "h:mm")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting to text and back to do the math just do the math and format the cell itself to `hh:mm`:

```
=(G3-F3+(G3<F3))-(TIME(0,45,0)*((G3-F3+(G3<F3))>TIME(5,0,0)))
```

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]